# How to replace a child Widget with state?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to replace a child StatefulWidget upon pressing a button. It works if the child is a StatelessWidget, and if the StatefulWidget doesn't actually have any state.

I'm relatively new to Flutter and I don't understand why this would happen. In my mind a new Widget  (regardless of whether it is Stateless or Stateful) is instantiated with new state, the child Widget is replaced in the setState() method, and the screen should be updated to reflect this.

Can anyone explain this to me?

I have written a short example to better illustrate my issue:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=5de8c8ef70d200d75a324ab85ff5e209

In the above example I would have expected both Containers to change color upon pressing the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the same widget for the second time and since you are setting the color inside the `initState`, the value won't be changed.

You have options like creating a new `StatefulWidget`, using the `key` property or using the old `Widget` with updated value.

Solution 1. To create a new `StatefulWidget`, you must set the `key` property like:

```
activeStatefulWidget = SimpleStatefulWidget(
  key: ValueKey(Random().nextInt(100)),
  color: Colors.blue,
);
```

Of course the key must be a unique value. In your example, widgets have different color so you can use: `key: ValueKey(Colors.blue.toString()),`.
For more information, take a look at: [Key class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html)  and [Widget key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html)

Solution 2. Update the value inside the `StatefulWidget`

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant SimpleStatefulWidget oldWidget) {
   color = widget.color;
   super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
}
```

Solution 3. Use `widget.color` inside `build` method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  color: widget.color,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
 );
}
```

Comment: Spot on! It was the absence of a 'key' property. I was unaware of the different trees involved in updating Widgets. As you say, the new instance of the StatefulWidget is the same type, and that is enough for the element tree to be considered unchanged. The combination of type and a different key are required to be seen as a different Widget.